# group_rows() function in kableExtra package not grouping rows

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to output a table in rmarkdown using the `kable()` as a part of the knitr package.  Below is one table that shows what I am trying to output with a built in data set.  The other is a subset of my data set.  When using my data set the output is not lining up and the code is basically the same.  I feel like I a missing something basic?  Please let me know! My code is below, and a picture of the output is below that.

````
```{r, results="asis"}
Table = kable(mtcars[1:10, 1:6], caption = "GOOD TABLE", booktabs = T, format="latex")
Table = kable_styling(Table) 
Table = group_rows(Table, "Group 1", 2, 4) 
group_rows(Table, "Group 2", 5, 6)
```

```{r, results="asis"}
Table = data.frame(MYDATA)
Table = kable(Table, caption = "BAD TABLE", booktabs = T, format="latex")
Table = kable_styling(Table) 
Table = group_rows(Table, "Group 1", 2, 4) 
group_rows(Table, "Group 2", 5, 6)
```
````

[image: Output Result]

Comment: I found that if I make adjustments to the table, like formatting or adding a percentage sign/money sign, I get the error I posted above.  If I remove this formatting the table works.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting!

This bug was produced by a mishandling of backslash in front of special inline symbols. It has been fixed in the current github version. Please use `devtools::install_github("haozhu233/kableExtra")` and install the latest version. Or you can wait for the CRAN version which will be release in about 2 weeks.

Comment: would you also have a hint to solve [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454558/kableextragroup-rows-grouping-not-working-for-last-row-in-long-table-and-n)? Many thanks in advance!