# kableExtra::pack_rows() - grouping not working for last row in long table and no indentation for wrapped text

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I use the `kableExtra` package to generate a long table in an R markdown documents knitted to PDF.

Sets of rows of the table are grouped together using `kableExtra::pack_rows()` (formerly `kableExtra::group_rows()`)

Two issues arise:

1. If the last row forms a set, its grouping is not displayed if one

   - sets `longtable = TRUE` to allow the long table to span across multiple pages

     *and* at the same time
   - uses `kable_styling(..., latex_options = c("repeat_header"))` to repeat the header of the table on each page.
2. The text in some rows of my first column is too long for the column width (which needs to be fixed). It is thus wrapped into the next line. However, any wrapped text is no longer indented. 
   Increasing the column width such that the text is unfortunately not an option in my use case.

I tried the minipage solution proposed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859270/indentation-when-line-break-in-group-rows-command-kableextra-package-in-r-ma) to solve issue 2).
It works if the first column is set sufficiently wide via `column_spec(1, width = "XXXem")`). However, in my use case, I can not set it soooo wide as to make it work this way.

If there is no other to indent the content of the wrapped line, could one alternatively remove the indentation in general?

An MWE and illustrations are provided below.

Either `longtable = FALSE` or no `latex_options = c("repeat_header"))` ==> Pack-rows is working

[image: Longtable-FALSE_Pack-rows-WORKING]

`longtable = TRUE` AND `latex_options = c("repeat_header"))` ==> Pack-rows is not working

[image: Longtable-TRUE_Pack-rows-NOT-WORKING]

````
---
title: "MWE"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---
```{r echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

dt <- mtcars[1:3, 1:2]

kable(dt, 
  escape = FALSE, # to be able to include latex commands
  booktabs = T, 
  longtable = TRUE, # allow long table to span multiple pages
  ) %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = F,
                latex_options = c(
                  "repeat_header"  # repeat header of long table
                )
  ) %>% 
  # column characteristics: set widths
  column_spec(1, width = "2cm") %>%
  # group rows together and give these groups labels
  pack_rows("Mazda Cars", 1, 2) %>%
  pack_rows("Datsun Cars", 3, 3)
```
````

Comment: FYI: For parts of the question, an issue has been filed by another user at [GitHub](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/476)

Comment: According to the author of the `kableExtra` package, the bug happened "when you use group_rows with repeat_header as repeat_header adds a * to the last row." and [has been fixed recently](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/476)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll have to leave this as an answer even though it's only a partial answer to the second part of your question. There is a way to remove all indentation in the pack_rows() function by using indent=FALSE:

```
kable(dt, 
  escape = FALSE, # to be able to include latex commands
  booktabs = T, 
  longtable = TRUE, # allow long table to span multiple pages
  ) %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = F,
                latex_options = c(
                  "repeat_header"  # repeat header of long table
                )
  ) %>% 
  # column characteristics: set widths
  column_spec(1, width = "2cm") %>%
  # group rows together and give these groups labels
  pack_rows("Mazda Cars", 1, 2, indent=FALSE) %>%
  pack_rows("Datsun Cars", 3, 3, indent=FALSE)
```

Unfortunately my table is quite long and would be much more readable if I could find a way to indent both parts of my long row name. So I'm still hoping for a better answer to this question. But I hope this helps someone!